# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined - highchart

Tags: database, string, variables

i try to draw a basic line chart with datas of my database in highchart. 
It works fine with static values. I read the datas of my database an generate string. When i try to use the strings as data values i get the following error-code:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

My .js Code

```
var $container = $('<div>').appendTo(document.body);

            window.chart=new Highcharts.Chart(
            {
                chart: {
                    renderTo: $container[0],
                    height: 400
                    },
                    title: 
                    {
                        text: ''
                    },

                    subtitle: 
                    {
                        text: ''
                    },
                    xAxis:  
                    {
                            title:  
                            {
                                        type: 'datetime'
                            }
                    },

                    yAxis: 
                    {
                        title: 
                        {
                            text: ''
                        }
                    },
                    tooltip: 
                    {
                        valueSuffix: '\xB0C'
                    },
                    legend: 
                    {
                        layout: 'vertical',
                        align: 'right',
                        verticalAlign: 'middle'
                    },

                    plotOptions: 
                    {
                        series: 
                        {
                            pointStart: Date.now() / 24 / 60 / 60 / 1000,
                            pointIntervall: 1 / 60 / 60 / 60 / 1000, 
                        }
                    },

                    series:
                    [
                        {
                            name: 'Frequenz [Hz]',
                            data: [<?php echo $FrequenzValues; ?>] 
                        }, 
                        {
                            name: 'Motorstrom [A]',
                            data: [<?php echo $StromValues; ?>]
                        }, 
                        {
                            name: 'Spannung MF11 [V]',
                            data: [<?php echo $MF_11Values; ?>]
                        }, 
                        {
                            name: 'Motorspannung [V]',
                            data: [<?php echo $SpannungValues; ?>]
                        }, 
                        {
                            name: 'Drehmoment [Nm]',
                            data: [<?php echo $DrehmomentValues; ?>]
                        },
                        {
                            name: 'Drehzahl [1/min]',
                            data: [<?php echo $DrehzahlValues; ?>]
                        }
                    ]
            });
```

The HTML-code

```html
<script src="es_scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="es_scripts/highcharts.js"></script>​
```

I create the strings in the function "GetChartsValue". I put the measured values together, separated by a comma and delete the last character

```
function getChartValues()
{
$q_data  = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Messwerte ORDER BY id DESC") or die(mysql_error()); 
    $n_data = mysql_num_rows($q_data);
    if($n_data > 0)
    {
        $FrequenzValues     = '';
        $StromValues        = '';
        $MF_11Values        = '';
        $SpannungValues     = '';
        $DrehmomentValues   = '';
        $DrehzahlValues     = '';
        $MPValues 

        = '';


    while($r_data = mysql_fetch_array($q_data))
    {           
        $FrequenzValues   .= $r_data['Frequenz'].',';       // Einzelne Werte durch Komma trennen
        $StromValues   .= $r_data['Strom'].',';             // Einzelne Werte durch Komma trennen           
        $MF_11Values   .= $r_data['MF_11'].',';             // Einzelne Werte durch Komma trennen           
        $SpannungValues   .= $r_data['Spannung'].',';       // Einzelne Werte durch Komma trennen           
        $DrehmomentValues   .= $r_data['Drehmoment'].',';   // Einzelne Werte durch Komma trennen           
        $DrehzahlValues   .= $r_data['Drehzahl'].',';       // Einzelne Werte durch Komma trennen           
        $MPValues .= $r_data['DatumZeit'].',';              // Einzelne Werte durch Komma trennen
    }

    $FrequenzValues      = delLastChar($FrequenzValues);     // Komma hinter dem letzten Temperaturwert entfernen
    $StromValues         = delLastChar($StromValues);        // Komma hinter dem letzten Temperaturwert entfernen
    $MF_11Values         = delLastChar($MF_11Values);        // Komma hinter dem letzten Temperaturwert entfernen
    $SpannungValues      = delLastChar($SpannungValues);     // Komma hinter dem letzten Temperaturwert entfernen
    $DrehmomentValues    = delLastChar($DrehmomentValues);   // Komma hinter dem letzten Temperaturwert entfernen
    $DrehzahlValues      = delLastChar($DrehzahlValues);     // Komma hinter dem letzten Temperaturwert entfernen
    $MPValues            = delLastChar($MPValues);       // Komma hinter letzter Stunde entfernen

    return array($FrequenzValues, $StromValues, $MF_11Values, $SpannungValues, $DrehmomentValues, $DrehzahlValues, $MPValues);
    }
}
```

Maybe you can see the mistake.

Comment: i found my mistake. There were empty rows in my database and the line chart